# A few familiar low-dimensional diffeomorphisms via algebraic geometry

Tags: algebraic-geometry, differential-topology

I am trying to understand something that for me is familiar fact in the study of 4-manifolds, however I am trying to understand it through the lens of algebraic geometry (which I sadly know very very little about).  The familiar fact is that $(S^2 x S^2) \sharp \overline{\mathbb{C}P^2}$ is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{C}P^2 \sharp \overline{\mathbb{C}P^2} \sharp \overline{\mathbb{C}P^2}$.  I've always thought of this as a fun first exercise in Kirby calculus and a complex analog of the result that $(S^1 \times S^1) \sharp \mathbb{R} P^2 = 3 \mathbb{R}P^2$.

I was reading [this article](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2372800) by Milnor where he proves that the prime decomposition of a 3-manifold is unique and a the end of the article he mentions the above diffeomorphism to illustrate how this uniqueness does not generalize to higher dimensions.  He also mentions a proof of this isomorphism due to Hirzebruch and it is this proof that I was hoping to get some help with.

First, we had better put our algebraic geometer hats on, so $S^2 \times S^2 = \mathbb{C}P^1 \times \mathbb{C}P^1$.  Now we are supposed to look at the expression
$$
(z_0 : z_1, z_2) \leftrightarrow (z_0 : z_1), (z_0 : z_2)
$$
I imagine we are supposed to think that this is a pair of functions
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{C}P^2 - \{(0:1:0), (0:0:1) \} &\to \mathbb{C}P^1 \times \mathbb{C}P^1 \\
      (z_0 : z_1 : z_2) &\mapsto ((z_0:z_1), (z_0:z_2))
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
 \mathbb{C}P^1 \times \mathbb{C}P^1 - {((0:1),(0:1))} &\to \mathbb{C}P^2\\
      ((z_0:z_1), (w_0:w_1)) &\mapsto (z_0 : z_1 : w_1 \frac{z_0}{w_0}) \text{ if } w_0 \neq 0\\
 &\mapsto (w_0 : z_1 \frac{w_0}{z_0} : w_1) \text{ if } z_0 \neq 0\\
\end{align*}
and note that these are inverses of each other, at least where composition makes sense.

Ok, so now what am I supposed to do?  Milnor says the word "blow-up" (which unfortunately doesn't mean anything to me) and I guess each of those missing points is going to contribute to a $\overline{\mathbb{C}P^2}$ summand being added.  Can someone explain this to me?

I imagine the same expression but where everything above is done over the real numbers gives a proof of the familiar fact about surfaces mentioned above.

Comment: I think this might be the fact that $\mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^1$ blown up at one point is isomorphic to $\mathbb{P}^2$ blown up at two points. If so, one thing you need to know is that blowing up a point on a smooth barrier replaces the point by its projectivized tangent space.

Comment: But, it could just be a coincidence. I’m a bit confused because blowing up a point on a surface replaces it by a $\mathbb{P}^1$, not another $\mathbb{P}^2$.

Comment: @Jake This is connected sum. Think about removing a disk from $\Bbb P^2$. You have the normal bundle of $\Bbb P^1$. Changing the orientation turns $\mathscr O(1)$ into $\mathscr O(-1)$, which is the normal bundle of your exceptional $\Bbb P^1$.

Comment: I see. It sounds like the connected sum picture corresponds to a neighborhood of the exceptional divisor, not just the exceptional divisor itself?

Comment: Jake When we take connected sum, we remove disks from both and glue along the boundary spheres that are left.